# How can I filter an SQLAlchemy query by ORM class?

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

I am using `declarative_base` for creating an ORM class hierarchy.  Now, I have a one-to-many relation (let's call it `related` between a class `Foo` and any subclasses of `CommonBase`), and I would like to be able to perform a query like "give me the `Foo`s that are related to any `Bar`".  I considered `filter()`ing like

```
session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.related.any(SUBCLASS_CHECK))
```

where SUBCLASS_CHECK should check whether the elements of `Foo.related` are of a particular class, e.g. `Bar`.

Of course, I am open for *any* solution and not limited to answers using `any()` in any way. :-)  This is just the direction that I was looking into.

Comment: Can you show us your model configuration?

Comment: The problem is that my model configuration is based on an additional abstraction layer (elixir-like), therefore it is rather hard to give a simple example.  However, I am not doing anything special.  My hope was that people recognize this pattern (1:n relationship with polymorphic classes, the actual type of which should be filtered) and can immediately answer with similarly mocked-up code fragments.

Comment: That's a little clearer. You didn't explicitly mention that you were doing polymorphism in the original post. I assume you're doing either joined or single table inheritance, where you have a discriminator column?